# Change of measure to get a determined drift

Tags: stochastic-calculus, girsanov

let's say I have a real stochastic process $dX_t=dt+\frac{1}{B_t}dB_t$ on $[0,T]$, with $B_t$  Brownian in $\mathbb{P}$ (not centered in 0) in $[0,\tau]$ with $\tau$ some adequate stopping time that makes everything good and smooth.

My exercise asks to find another prob. measure $\mathbb{Q}$ such that under this measure $X_t$ has a certain drift $\mu$, let's say $\mu=0$. Now the thing here is trying to apply Girsanov theorem. If that probability exists than we would have a shift of the Brownian of the form $dBt=dW_t+Y_tdt$.

Replacing $dB_t$ in the previous expression gives $dX_t=(1+\frac{Y_t}{B_t})dt+\frac{1}{B_t}dW_t \Rightarrow$ Imposing $drift=0$ we get $Y_t=-B_T$.

So with the substitution $dW_t=dB_t+B_tdt$ our process becomes driftless.

So we know that if exists, this probability is has the form of the R_N derivative $\dfrac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}=Z_t$, where $Z_t$ is the Dooleans-Dade exponential and that condition for that to happen according to Girsanov Theorem is that $Z_t$ is a martingale. For example, if Novikov conditions holds, i.e. if $E[e^{1/2(\int_0^tB_t^2ds)}]< \infty$, then it is a martingale and everything works.

Now my question is: what i just did makes some sense? I mean, when I impose the Brownian sustitution, than my $X_t$ becomes $dX_t=\frac{dW_t}{dB_t}$. This expression does make sense? $B_t$ was a brownian with respect to $\mathbb{P}$, now under the new probability measure i'm not sure it is even well defined as a stochastic process. I thought that being $\mathbb{Q}<<\mathbb{P}$ maybe this is not an issue, but i'm not sure. The alternative would be to replace $W_t$ also in $B_t$ but that would make the computations for $Y_t$ impossibles.

My second question is regarding the Novikov condition: $E[e^{1/2(\int_0^tB_t^2ds)}]< \infty$, this expectation should be take under $P$ or under $Q$?